# Getting one value out of a serialized array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

What would you say is the most efficient way to get a single value out of an Array. I know what it is, I know where it is. Currently I'm doing it with:

```
 $array = unserialize($storedArray);
 $var = $array['keyOne'];
```

Wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: You mean like a microoptimizationally faster way?

Comment: How much more concise do you want this to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it fine, I can't think of a better way than what you are doing.

- You unserialize
- You get an array
- You get value by specifying index

That's the way it can be done.

Comment: Ok. I was just making sure, so I don't make any tmp variables that I don't need.

Comment: @Methemer [Array dereferencing](http://razvantudorica.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/array-dereferencing-support-in-php-5-4-0/) is slated to be added in PHP 5.4, but it's not out yet. That would allow you to use one line and just do something like this: `$var = unserialize($storedArray)['keyOne'];`.

Answer (score 1):

> Wondering if there is a better way.

For the example you give with the array, I think you're fine.

If the serialized string contains data and objects you don't want to unserialize (e.g. creating objects you really don't want to have), you can use the [Serialized PHP library](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized) which is a complete parser for serialized data.

It offers low-level access to serialized data statically, so you can only extract a subset of data and/or manipulate the serialized data w/o unserializing it. However that looks too much for your example as you only have an array and you don't need to filter/differ too much I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Its most efficient way you can do, unserialize and get data, if you need optimize dont store all variables serialized.

Also there is always way to parse it with regexp :)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to unseralize the whole thing (which can be costly, especially for more complex objects), you can just do a strpos and look for the features you want and extract them

Comment: Aside from very specialized cases, this is most likely both more error-prone *and* inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.
If you need a better way - DO NOT USE serialized arrays.
Serialization is just a transport format, of VERY limited use.

If you need some optimized variant - there are hundreds of them.
For example, you can pass some single scalar variable instead of whole array. And access it immediately

Answer (score 0):

I, too, think the right way is to un-serialize.

But another way could be to use string operations, when you know what you want from the array:

```
$storedArray = 'a:2:{s:4:"test";s:2:"ja";s:6:"keyOne";i:5;}';
# another: a:2:{s:4:"test";s:2:"ja";s:6:"keyOne";s:3:"sdf";}
$split = explode('keyOne', $storedArray, 2);
# $split[1] contains the value and junk before and after the value
$splitagain = explode(';', $split[1], 3);
# $splitagain[1] should be the value with type information
$value = array_pop(explode(':', $splitagain[1], 3));
# $value contains the value
```

Now, someone up for a benchmark? ;)
Another way might be *RegEx* ?