# Wordpress plugin Gravity Forms (v. 1.9.6) is formatting JSON entries incorrectly?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

When I try to pull out some JSON from a Gravity Form entry, it appears to be formatted incorrectly and I get a syntax error whenever I put it in a JSON validator/try to decode it in PHP.

Here's the JSON I'm pulling:

```
a:40:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:61:"Somebody Bad Stole the Wedding Bell (Who's Got the Ding-Dong)";s:6:"Artist";s:11:"Eartha Kitt";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:1;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:7:"Hoy Hoy";s:6:"Artist";s:16:"The Collins Kids";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:2;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:12:"Funky Onions";s:6:"Artist";s:14:"Matthew Childs";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:3;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:20:"Dig That Crazy Chick";s:6:"Artist";s:28:"Sam Butera and the Witnesses";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:4;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:7:"Who Me?";s:6:"Artist";s:15:"The Jet Streams";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:5;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:14:"Sweet Nothin's";s:6:"Artist";s:9:"Peggy Lee";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:6;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:32:"You'd Be So Nice To Come Home To";s:6:"Artist";s:12:"Julie London";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:7;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:33:"Do the Dead Know What Time It Is?";s:6:"Artist";s:15:"Kenneth Patchen";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:8;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:13:"Hey, Bellboy!";s:6:"Artist";s:11:"Gloria Wood";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:9;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:26:"A Little Bit of Everything";s:6:"Artist";s:5:"Jocko";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:10;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:15:"C'est le Garcon";s:6:"Artist";s:13:"Gillian Hills";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:11;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:24:"Vous Dansez Mademoiselle";s:6:"Artist";s:6:"Valery";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:12;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:21:"Psychopathia Sexualis";s:6:"Artist";s:11:"Lenny Bruce";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:13;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:20:"Like Rumpelstiltskin";s:6:"Artist";s:10:"Don Morrow";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:14;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:29:"All That Meat and No Potatoes";s:6:"Artist";s:11:"Fats Waller";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:15;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:15:"Real Crazy Cool";s:6:"Artist";s:15:"Big Jay McNeely";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:16;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:48:"The Closer To the Bone (The Sweeter is the Meat)";s:6:"Artist";s:29:"Louis Prima and the Witnesses";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:17;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:15:"Nous Les Jeunes";s:6:"Artist";s:9:"Napoleona";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:18;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:10:"So In Love";s:6:"Artist";s:24:"Triks and the Paramounts";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:19;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:13:"A Petal a Day";s:6:"Artist";s:7:"Buttons";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:20;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:12:"Thanks A Lot";s:6:"Artist";s:9:"Bob Adams";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:21;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:26:"La Noche que Murio Chicago";s:6:"Artist";s:11:"Banda Macho";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:22;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:9:"Dumb Head";s:6:"Artist";s:12:"Genny Arnell";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:23;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:16:"I'm the Wolf Man";s:6:"Artist";s:11:"Round Robin";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:24;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:19:"The Big White House";s:6:"Artist";s:11:"Jess Conrad";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:25;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:12:"Mystery Girl";s:6:"Artist";s:11:"Jess Conrad";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:26;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:13:"Lonesome Town";s:6:"Artist";s:12:"Ricky Nelson";s:8:"Comments";s:7:"REQUEST";}i:27;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:20:"Ah, Poor Little Baby";s:6:"Artist";s:22:"Billy "Crash" Craddock";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:28;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:26:"Will His Love Be Like Rum?";s:6:"Artist";s:15:"Harry Belafonte";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:29;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:17:"Sono Qui Con Vois";s:6:"Artist";s:16:"Caterina Caselli";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:30;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:6:"La Mer";s:6:"Artist";s:12:"Martin Denny";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:31;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:12:"Gopher Mambo";s:6:"Artist";s:9:"Yma Sumac";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:32;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:13:"Rockin' Bones";s:6:"Artist";s:13:"Ronnie Dawson";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:33;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:15:"I Make the Love";s:6:"Artist";s:13:"Ronnie Dawson";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:34;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:20:"You're My Everything";s:6:"Artist";s:13:"Jerry Colonna";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:35;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:27:"Down By the Old Mill Stream";s:6:"Artist";s:13:"Jerry Colonna";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:36;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:18:"Serenade to a Jerk";s:6:"Artist";s:11:"Spike Jones";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:37;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:32:"I Wanna Go Back to West Virginia";s:6:"Artist";s:11:"Spike Jones";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:38;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:22:"I Don't Need No Doctor";s:6:"Artist";s:12:"Nick Ashford";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}i:39;a:3:{s:4:"Song";s:9:"Mel Torme";s:6:"Artist";s:16:"Coming Home Baby";s:8:"Comments";s:0:"";}}
```

Comment: I'm using the PHP wrapper found at the end of the API guide site.

Answer (score 0):

Determined it was a serialized array from this post:
[Wordpress Gravity Forms get List values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269983/wordpress-gravity-forms-get-list-values?rq=1)

Was able to finish the code from there.